# if $f(x)f(-x) = 0, \forall x \in\mathbb{R}$ can we prove that $f(x)=0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, proof-verification, functional-equations

I know that if $f(x)g(x) = 0$, that doesn't imply $g(x)=0$ or $f(x)=0$ (there many counterexamples). However how can i prove this ?

Comment: No, $f(x) = \chi_{[0,\infty)}$.

Comment: Is $f$ continuous?

Comment: @myglasses: $f(x)=x$ for $x\geq0$ and $f(x)=0$ for  $x<0$ is continous.

Comment: No, but it implies that for ever $x$ either $f(x) = 0$ or $g(x) = 0$.  So $f(0)f(0) = 0$ so $f(0) = 0$.. and for any $x\in\mathbb R^+$ then either f(x) = 0 or f(-x) = 0.  But it is easy to come up with functions that aren't constant where that is true.  f can even be continuous and differential and still be true.  (I don't think f can be smooth but I'm not sure about that).

Comment: @fleablood: $f(x)=\exp(-1/x^2)$ for $x>0$, $f(x)=0$ for $x\le 0$ is smooth.

Comment: @gammatester Yeah, that's a good counter example.  (I did say I wasn't sure...)

Comment: I don't think that there are any real-analytic counterexamples, however.

Comment: @MyGlasses no, because for every y either f(y) or f(-y) must be equal to zero.  So f(x)=0 must occur uncountably often.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Do you mean that $f:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$, f analytic ,so that $f(x)f(-x)=0$ for all real $x$ has no counter examples?  Or that so that $f(x)f(-x) = 0$ for all complex $x$ has no counter examples?

Comment: Actually, $f(x) g(x) = 0$ **does** imply that $f(x)=0$ or $g(x)=0$. What you mean is that $fg = 0$ doesn't imply that $f=0$ or $g=0$. To be more precise, $\forall x : f(x) g(x) = 0$ does imply $\forall x : \left( f(x) = 0 \vee g(x) = 0 \right)$ but not $\left( \forall x : f(x) = 0 \right) \vee \left( \forall x : g(x) = 0 \right).$

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=0$ for $x\geq0$ and $f(x)=1$ for all $x<0$.

Answer (score 0):

Take any non-identically-zero function $f$. Let $A=\{x:f(x)\ne 0\}$. Of course, by the assumption $A\ne\varnothing$. Define $g(x)=0$ on $A$ and $g(x)=\text{whatever you want}$ for $x\not\in A$.

Comment: Take $f = \chi_{\langle -\infty, -1]\cup[1, +\infty\rangle}$ so $A = \langle -\infty, -1]\cup[1, +\infty\rangle$. Define $g = \chi_{\langle-1, 1\rangle}$. Then $g\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)g\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)=1$.

Comment: I have suggested by the 1st sentence of the OP. :)